# "Your Ruby version is 2.1.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.1" I receive this error even I use simple command like rails new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have tried different answers from other posts but none is work. I cloned a project from github, and receive this error 'Your Ruby version is 2.1.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.1' while running bundle install/update.

It was originally specified ruby '2.1.1' in gemfile, but I still receiving the same error after removing ruby '2.1.1' from gemfile.

UPDATE:

Ok problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Rails 2.x applications the version is also defined in `config/environment.rb`. Search for `RAILS_GEM_VERSION` and update the version number in that file too.